# Displaying API information after a button push

Tags: javascript, api

So I am trying to display the information for a random quote from an API after they click a button on screen. However, the button displays, and the information is run in the console when it loads on the page, but it does not display on the page at all yet, even though I set it up to display immediately when the page loads. Any ideas on how I can fix this?

```
const output = (quoteInfo) => {
    quoteInfo.forEach(
        quotes => {
            let article = document.createElement('article');
        
            let anime = document.createElement("h4");
            anime.textContent = quotes.anime;

            let quote = document.createElement("h3");
            quote.textContent = quotes.quote;

            let character = document.createElement("h4");
            character.textContent = quotes.character;

            article.appendChild(anime);
            article.appendChild(quote);
            article.appendChild(character);

            document.querySelector("#quote").appendChild(article);
       }
   
   );
}

const URL = "https://animechan.vercel.app/api/random"
const buttonElement = document.getElementById("submitButton");
fetch("https://animechan.vercel.app/api/random")
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(quotes => console.log(quotes))

//const reset = () => {
    //document.querySelector("#quote").innerHTML = " ";
    //}

 //buttonElement.addEventListener("click", reset())
```

Comment: You never call your `output` function.  The only thing you do with the API response is log it to the console, which explains why the only thing that happens is that it logs to the console.  Maybe replace `console.log(quotes)` with `output(quotes)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ItsYaboi123](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16422659/itsyaboi123), I think you are missing load event to the window in your script. You can do that by using the `window.addEventListener()` method which takes two required parameters. The first one is `event` and the second one is a `callback` function that **returns a value.**

I am assuming that your API is returning an array something like this:

```js
let info = [
    {
        anime: "Fate/zero",
        character: "Rider",
        quote: "To win, but not destroy"
    },
    {
        anime: "Hai to Gensou no Grimgar",
        character: "Shinohara",
        quote: "I understand the pain of losing a comrade."
    }

];
```

So, your `output()` function would be like this:

```js
function output() {
    return info.forEach((pack) => {
        const { anime, character, quote } = pack;  // destructuring
        let article = document.createElement('article');

        let animeElement = document.createElement("h4");
        animeElement.textContent = pack.anime;

        let quoteElement = document.createElement("h3");
        quoteElement.textContent = pack.quote;

        let characterElement = document.createElement("h4");
        characterElement.textContent = pack.character;

        article.appendChild(animeElement);
        article.appendChild(quoteElement);
        article.appendChild(characterElement);

        let quotes = document.getElementById('quotes');
        quotes.appendChild(article);

    });

}

window.addEventListener('load', output);
```

I hope its works for you!!

**Edit:**

In case you want to display the results with a button click, then you need to refactor the code as follows:

```js
let info = [
    {
        anime: "Fate/zero",
        character: "Rider",
        quote: "To win, but not destroy; to conquer, but not humiliate: That is what true conquest is!"
    },
    {
        anime: "Hai to Gensou no Grimgar",
        character: "Shinohara",
        quote: "I understand the pain of losing a comrade."
    }

];

function output() {
    info.forEach((pack) => {
        const { anime, character, quote } = pack;  // destructuring
        let article = document.createElement('article');

        let animeElement = document.createElement("h4");
        animeElement.textContent = pack.anime;

        let quoteElement = document.createElement("h3");
        quoteElement.textContent = pack.quote;

        let characterElement = document.createElement("h4");
        characterElement.textContent = pack.character;

        article.appendChild(animeElement);
        article.appendChild(quoteElement);
        article.appendChild(characterElement);

        let quotes = document.getElementById('quotes');
        quotes.appendChild(article);

    });

}
function helper() {

    // button
    let btn = document.getElementById('btn');
    // add event listener to the button which triggered output()
    btn.addEventListener('click', output);
}

window.addEventListener('load', helper);
```